# Print order page - group price is not displaying

Tags: magento2.3.1, group-price

In print order view page, price column is not displaying the correct customer group price, but normal retail price.

In subtotal column though, the correct group price is displayed.

How can I fix that? Is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: For it you have to override and pass that price you want to print, is it bug or not you can perform same steps on new fresh magento.